# error to login after upgrade from joomla 3.6.0 to joomla 3.6.1

Tags: joomla-3.x

After upgrading from joomla 3.6.0 to joomla 3.6.1, joomla suddenly bakend page was blank.

try to enter to admisnitrator page, and get this error:

Se ha producido un error.

```
0 Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set).
```

Try suggestions from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11430 but nothing changed.

any help?

Comment: On my site, attempting to log in to the back end gives me the same error. The front end is fine unless I try to log in, at which point I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joomla 3.6.0 to 3.6.1 results in a "invalid security token" error](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17356/joomla-3-6-0-to-3-6-1-results-in-a-invalid-security-token-error)

Answer (score 3):

This issue has to do with your server running an old version of PHP (5.3) and a bug in Joomla 3.6.1. **[Joomla 3.6.2](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5667-joomla-3-6-2-released.html) was released a couple of hours ago, and should fix this problem.**

> ## What's in 3.6.2
>
> Joomla! 3.6.2 fixes some issues found in the 3.6.1 release on
> Wednesday related to sessions on PHP 5.3 and some general email
> cloaking bugs

Although the minimum requirements for running Joomla is PHP 5.3, this version reached [EOL (End Of Life)](http://php.net/eol.php) almost two years ago, and it's considered a security risk to use it on a live server. You should check with your hosting provider how (or if) you can update to a more recent version, like PHP 5.6 or even [PHP 7](https://www.gavick.com/blog/joomla-php-7-speedtest).

Answer (score 2):

This fix worked for me:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11430/files

It involves three small changes to the Joomla file `libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php`.

Comment: helped me - thx!

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

This fix worked for me too:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11430/files

It involves three small changes to the Joomla file libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php.

Thanks for help me fix it!!