# Joomla 3.4.x to 3.6.4 Update and invalid security token on front-end login

Tags: joomla-3.4, login, joomla-3.6, update, security-token

I have to update a Joomla 3.4.7 site. I did first a localhost update to test - everything worked fine.

But now on the live site I am not able to login in the front-end. I am getting the invalid security token issue. Backend login works just fine.

I re-installed Joomla through com_joomlaupdate and generally have tried  anything I could think to address the issue, but still nothing.

I did the same with manual installation but again the issue remains.

Is it possible that I am not using the right package? Reviewing the documentation:

- https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.6.4
- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5

It's not that clear which package I should use.
Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solving my issue

Well in my case the issue was not related to Joomla core. I had to step away from it for a while and return with clear mind to find out that it was a custom directive inside the htaccess that was causing this issue.

It looks like someone wanted to prevent access to the `com_users` component in the front-end.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \boption=com_users\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Removing this - solved the front-end login issue.

---

### Update - Front-end Login using Modules

For anyone that reaches to this page with this front-end login issue, I have noticed that using some **login modules** for front-end login may produce the above issue.
In this case make sure your login modules have their **cache** setting to **No-Caching** (disabled).

I am not sure for the core login module - but have seen this with 3rd party ones.

Comment: Wow, what an odd thing to add. Glad you found the issue

Comment: @Lodder: it bugged me that much... you know when facing a problem, the problem puts a cloud around it - and sometimes the solution can be just next to you. That happened with me - I tried everything and never thought to check or disable the htaccess - I was using the same one I found on the site as is. After taking a break for a nap - I returned fresh and managed to think clearer. In the next 10 minutes it was resolved. So best advise when a solution isn't looking close - take a break away of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The invalid security token was an issue in the Joomla 3.6.1 update. To fix this, please see my answer here, which also caters for user who have Akeeba Backup installed:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/17357/168

The package you need to be using for the update is this:

[Joomla_3.6.x_to_3.6.4-Stable-Patch_Package.zip](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.6.4/Joomla_3.6.x_to_3.6.4-Stable-Patch_Package.zip) (*direct download link*)

Hope this helps

Comment: hmm, do you have any page caching enabled?

Comment: no cache enabled - this thing is bugging me for second day now...

Comment: Someone had the same problem as you but was cache related somehow: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/12566. By the way, ere you sure you're site is now running on J3.6.4 now?

Comment: yes 3.6.4 - but I started again from scratch and I am taking all the way up from 3.4.7 ... so right now I am at 3.6.0 - do you think the 3.6.0 to 3.6.4 package will work ?

Comment: it should work. Perhaps try installing the 4 updates separately, so `3.6.0 >> 3.6.1`, then `3.6.1 >> 3.6.1`, etc. And after each update, try logging in via the frontend

Comment: I did everything from scratch - step by steps updates - even that joomlaupdate component update - It works fine on localhost - but when online it keeps giving me the issue.

Comment: What happens if you create a new account and try to login with that?

Comment: the same happens for new accounts also

Comment: Very odd. I'd suggest posting a comment on the Joomla Github Repo (Iseues)

Comment: I sorted it out. It wasn't Joomla - it was htaccess causing this.